# iOS - SKReverseGeocoderService reverseGeocoding gives generalised result not detailed

Tags: ios, skmaps

I am using `SKMap` sdk from skobbler, everything works great, but while developing further, I found that the SDK doesn't provide much detailed information when I do offline geocoding, that is my requirement.

I am using following code

```
SKSearchResult *searchObject =  [[SKReverseGeocoderService sharedInstance] reverseGeocodeLocation:coordinate];
```

Below I have demonstrate how the reverse geolocation giving generalised result mostly it gives you Street Names, rather than building, or location details, see the demo below I am pointing pin on a building it gives me adjacent street name always.

[image]

The problem I am facing is, I need to save the location as bookmark, so if I have couple of location nearby, I always get the street name which doesn't allow me to distinguish the saved bookmarks.

Please help, if I am missing anything, I am using the map completely **offline**.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Our reverse geocoder only returns address information (no house number), it does not return POI information.